# Is $f^{\prime \prime}_{xy}(0,0) = f^{\prime \prime}_{yx}(0,0)$ for the given function?

Tags: partial-derivative

Let
$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} xy,\,\,\, |y| \leq |x| \\ -xy,\,\,\, |y| > |x|
\end{cases}$

Here is what I've done.

$f^{\prime}_x = \cases{y,\,\,\,|y| \leq|x|\\-y,\,\,\,|y|>|x|}$
$f^{\prime}_y = \cases{x,\,\,\,|y| \leq|x|\\-x,\,\,\,|y|>|x|}$

$f^{\prime\prime}_{xy} = \cases{1,\,\,\,|y| \leq|x|\\-1,\,\,\,|y|>|x|}$
$f^{\prime\prime}_{yx} = \cases{1,\,\,\,|y| \leq|x|\\-1,\,\,\,|y|>|x|}$

And from here the answer seems yes, but the book says otherwise. Now, I think that it is right what I did in the first step and that the problem is in the second step, where I might be calculating the second order partial derivatives wrongly. Is it so? If yes, then what is the correct way of calculating partial derivatives of second order for such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's compute $f_x'(0,y)$:

It's easy to see that
$$ f(x,0)=0,\qquad \forall x.$$

Then
$$ f_x'(0,0)=0.$$.

When $y\neq0$,it's easy to see that
$$ f(x,y)=-xy,\qquad \forall |x|<|y|.$$

So we have
$$ f_x'(0,y)=-y,\qquad \forall y\neq0. $$

Hence we have
$$ f_x'(0,y)=-y,\qquad \forall y.$$

So we have
$$ f_{xy}''(0,0)=-1.$$

Secondly, let's compute $f_y'(x,0)$.

It's easy to see that
$$ f(0,y)=0,\qquad \forall y.$$

Then
$$ f_y'(0,0)=0.$$

When $x\neq0$,we have
$$ f(x,y)=xy,\qquad \forall |y|<|x|.$$

Then
$$ f_y'(x,0)=x,\qquad \forall x\neq0.$$

Hence
$$ f_y'(x,0)=x,\qquad \forall x.$$

So
$$ f_{yx}''(0,0)=1.$$

Therefore,
$$f_{xy}''(0,0)\neq f_{yx}''(0,0).$$

Comment: oh, so the overall idea is that the relation between $|y|$ and $|x|$ may not be the same for different orders of $x$ and $y$ when computing the second order derivatives?

Comment: @H-a-y-K Yes, you need to compute $f_{xy}''(0,0)$ and $f_{yx}''(0,0)$ only using the definition, independently.